# Algoritmo que une dos arrays ordenados

Tags: c, ordenamiento, manejo-de-memoria

estoy leyendo el libro Introducción a los Algoritmos (Cormen) en el cual implementamos
*merge-sort* utilizando una función llamada *merge* que combina dos sub-arrays ordenados en uno
solo, el código es el siguiente:

```
void
merge (int vec[], size_t left, size_t mid, size_t right){
    size_t i, j, k;
    size_t siz1 = mid - left;
    size_t siz2 = right - mid;
    int * vleft = calloc (siz1, sizeof(int));
    int * vright = calloc (siz2, sizeof(int));


    /* copying the corresponding subarrays */
    vleft = memcpy (vleft, vec + left, siz1 * sizeof(int));
    vright = memcpy (vright, vec + mid, siz2 * sizeof(int));

    i = j = 0;
    for (k = left; k < right; k++){
        if (vleft [i] <= vright [j])
            vec[k] = vleft [i++];
        else
            vec[k] = vright [j++];
    }

    free (vleft);
    free (vright);
}

int
main (void){
    int v[] = {48, 59, 61, 79, 12, 21, 32, 58};
    merge (v, 0, 4, 8);
    print_array(v, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

Después de llamar a merge() se llama a print_array() y la salida debería ser

```
12 21 32 48 58 59 61 79
```

Sin embargo es:

```
12 21 32 48 58 0 0 59
```

No sé qué parte de mi código este fallando, sin embargo he notado que la función calloc() almacena más memoria de la que le pedí, por ejemplo en la línea `vright = calloc(siz2, sizeof(int))` se debería almacenar espacio para 4 enteros, en su lugar se almacenan mucho más (lo verifique con un bucle que imprimia los valores almacenados en vleft hasta obtener un *segmentation fault*). Creo que esta puede ser la razón de fallar de la función merge, pero aún no tengo claro por qué esto pasa y como solucionarlo.

Gracias de antemano por las respuestas!

Comment: Usa un address sanitizer. Ese te avisara cuando toques memoria que no reservaste, con eso lo tendras mas claro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por los comentarios explicando el comportamiento de calloc(). Ya logré solucionarlo: (Los nombres de las variables cambiaron un poco ya que borré la función y luego no recordaba que había puesto)

```
static void
merge(int * vec, size_t left, size_t mid, size_t right){
    size_t lsiz, rsiz;
    size_t i, j, k;
    int *lvec, *rvec;

    i = j = 0;
    k = left;
    lsiz = mid - left + 1;
    rsiz = right - mid;
    lvec = calloc(lsiz, sizeof(int));
    rvec = calloc(rsiz, sizeof(int));

    /* copying the corresponding subarrays */
    memcpy(lvec, vec + left, sizeof(int)*lsiz);
    memcpy(rvec, vec + mid + 1, sizeof(int)*rsiz);

    /* Since lsiz and rsiz are less or equal to right, there
     * is no need to check if K exceeded the array limit. */
    for (; i < lsiz && j < rsiz; k++){
        if (lvec[i] <= rvec[j])
            vec[k] = lvec[i++];
        else
            vec[k] = rvec[j++];
    }

    /* Copying the reamining part of the subarray that is not completely
     * merged to vec */
    memcpy(vec + k, lvec + i, (lsiz - i)*sizeof(int));
    memcpy(vec + k, rvec + j, (rsiz - j)*sizeof(int));

    free(lvec);
    free(rvec);
}
```

La solución es verificar el valor de `i` y el de `j` en lugar del de `k`. Ya que el límite de `i` y `j` es `lsiz` o `rsiz` respectivamente, ambos límites son menores que `right` por lo tanto k no llegará a ser menor que el límite derecho del array.

Cuando uno de los dos índices llega a su límite, el subarray correspondiente se ha "vaciado", entonces sólo debemos copiar lo que queda del otro array. Para esto se utilizan las líneas

```
memcpy(vec + k, lvec + i, (lsiz - i)*sizeof(int));
memcpy(vec + k, rvec + j, (rsiz - j)*sizeof(int));
```

la diferencia en el tercer argumento de memcpy hace innecesario encontrar cual de los dos subarrays se ha vaciado.